# remove quotes while appending objects to the list

Tags: python

I am reading data from csv and my task is to convert few fields from that csv data to JSON objects and then finally print those JSON objects as a list.

Sample csv data:

```
"Station","Longitude","Latitude","Ubication","District Name","Neighborhood Name"
"Barcelona - Ciutadella","2.1874","41.3864","Parc de la Ciutadella","Ciutat Vella","Sant Pere, Santa Caterina i la Ribera"
"Barcelona - Eixample","2.1538","41.3853","Av. Roma - c/ Comte Urgell","Eixample","la Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample"
"Barcelona - Gràcia","2.1534","41.3987","Plaça Gal·la Placídia (Via Augusta - Travessera de Gràcia)","Gracia","la Vila de Gracia"
```

Output:

```
['{"Station": "Barcelona - Ciutadella", "District Name": "Ciutat Vella"}', '{"Station": "Barcelona - Eixample", "District Name": "Eixample"}', '{"Station": "Barcelona - Gr\\u00e0cia", "District Name": "Gracia"}', '{"Station": "Barcelona - Palau Reial", "District Name": "Les Corts"}', '{"Station": "Barcelona - Poblenou", "District Name": "Sant Marti"}', '{"Station": "Barcelona - Sants", "District Name": "Sants-Montjuic"}', '{"Station": "Barcelona - Vall Hebron", "District Name": "Horta-Guinardo"}', '{"Station": "Barcelona - Vallvidrera, el Tibidabo i les Planes", "District Name": "Sarri\\u00e0-Sant Gervasi"}']
```

Expected output:

```
[...,{"Station":"Barcelona - Vallvidrera, El Tibidabo I Les Planes","District Name":"Sarri\u00e0-Sant Gervasi"}, {"Station: ..., "District Name":"...}, ...]
```

The part where I am facing problem is How to remove quotes while printing a list of objects.

Code:

```
with open('air_stations_Nov2017.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf=8') as file:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=",")
    json_data = []
    for item in csv_file:
        json_data.append(json.dumps({'Station':item['Station'],'District Name':item['District Name']}))
    print(json_data)
```

Kindly advice me on how to remove the quotes and print the data.
I tried `print(','.join(json_data))` but that just joins all the objects and prints them without the list.

Hope you guys got my problem.

Comment: you save the dict in the loop, then in the end use `json.dump`. Replace `json_data.append(json.dumps({'Station':item['Station'],'District Name':item['District Name']}))` with `json_data.append({'Station':item['Station'],'District Name':item['District Name']})`; then after the loop `json.dump(file, json_data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do JSON dumps while appending dict in json_data list.
First fill the list then do the json dump.
I have changed your code:

```
with open('air_stations_Nov2017.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf=8') as file:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=",")
    json_data = []
    for item in csv_file:
        json_data.append({'Station':item['Station'],'District Name':item['District Name']})
    print(json.dumps(json_data))
```